# AttributeError: module 'facebook' has no attribute 'GraphAPI'

Tags: python

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'facebook' has no attribute 'GraphAPI'
```

When I run the following code:

```
import facebook
import re
token = "EAA..." # removed my access token for security reasons
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("100036636053395")
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'],"posts")
for post in posts['data']:
    try:
        graph.put_object(post['id'],"likes")
    except:
        continue
```

Knowing that I made sure my python script is NOT named `facebook`. I'm using python3 and I've installed the `facebook` module using:

```
pip3 install facebook-sdk
```

Comment: Where is the code causing the problem? Also, we need to know more information about your problem like you have installed a module called `facebook` using `pip` ... something like that

Comment: i have installed the facebook module with pip.

Comment: What is the command used to install `facebook`?

Comment: pip3 install facebook-sdk

Comment: Try `facebook.GraphAPI(token, version="2.21")`

Comment: i get the same error as last time

Comment: what is the result when running this piece of code `print(facebook.__version__)`?

Comment: i get this error: AttributeError: module 'facebook' has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: Do you have any script called `facebook` within the same folder? If yes, then that's the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've added the answer. It could help other people :)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was that there is some file called `facebook.py` in the working directory. So, when the Original Poster was running `import facebook`, it didn't import the `facebook-sdk` package, but it imported the script.

How to solve this? simple, rename your script so the interpreter doesn't get confused.